# Sprite-kit - Facing the hero? ( rotating to the direction of another node)

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have two spriteNodes hero and the enemy, both with rectangular physicsBody applied. 
In the update, when the hero gets to the certain point, e.g  hero.position.y <=  300 I want the enemy to rotate and face the the hero as it moves down.

the only sample code I found was the [Adventure from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/AdventureArchitecture/AdventureArchitecture.html) which has a faceTo class but I found it very complicated to use. I am looking for a nice and clean solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the xScale property of the SKSpriteNode. Setting xScale to -1.0 will make the sprite face the other way.

Comment: However, this might cause a problem with the physicsBody of the sprite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic implementation should look something like this:

```
- (void)rotateNode:(SKNode *)nodeA toFaceNode:(SKNode *)nodeB {

    CGFloat angle = atan2f(nodeB.position.y - nodeA.position.y, nodeB.position.x - nodeA.position.x);

    if (nodeA.zRotation < 0) {
        nodeA.zRotation = nodeA.zRotation + M_PI * 2;
    }

    [nodeA runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:angle duration:0]];
}
```

It's important that you understand what is happening. Look up and read about atan2 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) and try to understand how the code above works.

Comment: Wouldn't this make the sprite upside down?

Comment: This is assuming that your game is from a top-down perspective. I'm assuming it is since you referenced Apple's Adventure demo.

Comment: Oh ok. Then this would be suitable.

Comment: Thanks henryeverett , a 101 beginner question, how do you then get a use of that code in the update: I have the follwing following `        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"enemy" usingBlock:^(SKNode *enemy, BOOL *stop) {    `
        
              if (hero.position.y <= 300 ){
       // [enemy toFaceNode:hero ]; No visible @interface for 'SKNode'declares the selector 'toFaceNode:'
  
              }

    }];

Comment: It's telling you that you haven't implemented a method called toFaceNode: in the "enemy" class. Make sure you have implemented the method correctly in the .m file and referenced it in the .h file.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xScale property of SKNode to make the sprite face the other way. This can be done by setting:

```
sprite.xScale = -1.0;
```

However, this has been proved to cause problems with the `physicsBody`, as can be seen from this question:

[Flipped x-scale breaks collision handling (SpriteKit 7.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454220/flipped-x-scale-breaks-collision-handling-spritekit-7-1)

The solution for this problem is given there itself by [JKallio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2939228/jkallio).

He suggests keeping your sprite as a child of another SKNode (to which you apply the physicsBody) and changing the xScale property of the child node where needed. This is what I am using in my own project as well.