# SpriteKit SKPhysicsBody broken collisions

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a `SKSpriteNode` which has a static body, generated from *concave path* with `edgeChainFromPath`. Let's call this node a **house**.

I also have another kind of `SKSpriteNode`s which have a dynamic square body, generated with `rectangleOfSize`. Let's call this node a **box**.

In my scene, the **boxes** are thrown aka impulsed into the **house** and since both of them have bodies, the **boxes** should collide with the **house** and bounce away.

I'm scrolling the scene and therefore creating new instances of EXACTLY THE SAME **house** described above.

The **problem** I'm having is that collisions are completely or partially broken for some **houses**. Some **houses** collide with **boxes** exactly as they should, some collide with **boxes** only on some random segments of the body, and some completely ignore collisions with the **boxes**.

This problem only happens on iPad and never on iPhone. Happens both on iPad Simulator and real iPad device.

The problem occurs completely random and on random **houses**.

I also tried creating **house** body with `edgeLoopFromPath` but the problem remains.

Also, I'm drawing the physics and can see that the physics body of the **house** is exactly as it should be.

There is nothing else special about the scene or nodes that would be worth telling about.

I'm using `SpriteKit` with `Swift` in `iOS 9`.

---

**Update**:

Seems like the issue is in setting the scale on **house** nodes. I have to do that in order to have universal look on all screen sizes.

Still looking for solution/workaround...

Comment: Have you enabled visual physics representation and checked that everything looks fine?

Comment: @Whirlwind like I said: "I'm drawing the physics". So yes. :)

Comment: Do you have fast moving objects on the scene? Also if you are manually changing positions of nodes which can collide, then you can get weird behaviour...

Comment: @Whirlwind Yes, **boxes** are fast moving objects, since they are impulsed but it doesn't matter how fast they move. I've tried changing the velocity and I still get the same results. Talking about manually changing positions: I'm *not* manually changing the position of any node in the scene. I'm scrolling the scene by moving the new camera node, introduced in iOS 9.

Comment: 1) Try to set usesPreciseCollisionDetection on fast moving objects, just see if changes anything. Double check if you don't manually change the position on any node which participates in physics simulation. By manually changing I mean changing position property directly, or by using SKaction.moveXxx methods.

Comment: @Whirlwind Actually, I'm using `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` on **boxes** right now. The issue remains if I turn this off as well. I'm 100% sure I'm not changing the position of any node after it's added to the scene in any way. I've also tried changing the size of **boxes** to make them really big but that doesn't matter either. :/

Comment: Well the you can upload a git repo which can reproduce the issue you are talking about and hopefully somebody will look at it.

Comment: @Whirlwind will try to do that, yes. Thanks for your time so far! +1

Comment: @Whirlwind Seems like it is `scale` that I'm applying to **house** nodes that messes up their physics body. Do you know any way to get around that? Definitely seems like a bug in SpriteKit since it works sometimes...

Comment: Well personally I've seen that scaling a physics body sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  But it was like, it just works, or it doesn't work at all (this was based mostly on iOS version). Your case is specific. Never seen that, so I can't comment any further. In general, scaling physics bodies was often a problematic goal.

Comment: @Whirlwind yes, seems like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to edgeLoopFromPath creating a hollow box with an edge for your house, not one with volume.

I would try using [bodyWithPolygonFromPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithPolygonFromPath:) as well as adding preciseCollisionDetection to both your boxes and houses.